# Create slider to divide a variable over turtles

Tags: slider, netlogo

I am modelling the willingness for industries at a port to invest in Carbon Capture and Storage (CCS) technology with a given subsidy. I have two different breeds, the port and industries. I have 15M EUR of subsidy each year available. Is there a way to divide this subsidy over the agents with a slider so that I can change the dispatch each year? Thanks for any help!

Max

Comment: You'll probably want to create a slider for % port, and then make 15 M * %port port turtles, and the remaining industry turtles.

Comment: Thanks! That worked:)